# IE9 class calls in an external css stylesheet not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm currently running this code. I also have an external stylesheet that applies all my styles of the page correctly but i'm running in this issue at the moment.

When i call .ie9 as a class in my external stylesheet and want to apply a gradient style to it, it isn't running my code in the Internet Explorer emulation.

However when i run the code not in the .ie9 class the code actually works so i made some mistake somewhere. Perhaps you might know what the issue is here.

**HTML Code:**

```
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html lang="nl-NL"> <!--![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.ie9 {
    .section-example{
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#80c9db', EndColorStr='#30aac8');     
     }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `.ie9 .someclass {  }`

Comment: Ah yes that was actually the issue here, just implemented the class calls wrong. Thanks for helping me out Nick R!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually different. Internet Explorer 11 emulator does not load conditional html statements for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

May it works for greater than ie9:-

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/css/ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```